# Get unique values across two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | col_1            | col_2 
------+------------------+-------------------
 1 |               12 |                15
 2 |               12 |                16
 3 |               12 |                17
 4 |               13 |                18
 5 |               14 |                18
 6 |               14 |                19
 7 |               15 |                19
 8 |               16 |                20
```

I know if I do something like this, it will return all unique values from col_1:

```
select distinct(col_1) from table;
```

Is there a way I can get the distinct values across two columns? So my output would only be:

```
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

That is, it would take the distinct values from `col_1` and add them to `col_2`'s distinct values while also removing any values that are in both distinct lists (such as `15` which appears in both `col_1` and `col_2`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `UNION`

```
select col_1
from the_table
union 
select col_2
from the_table;
```

`union` implies a `distinct` operation, the above is the same as:

```
select distinct col
from (
  select col_1 as col
  from the_table
  union all
  select col_2 as col
  from the_table
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `union`

```
select col1 from table
union
select col2 from table;
```

You will not need `distinct` here because a `union` automatically does that for you (as opposed to a `union all`).